# Ruby Rails <%= yield %> doesn't display bootstrap footer correctly

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap

I'm developing with bootstrap and Ruby on Rails which is going great except with something that a lot of people seem to have problems with; adding a footer at the bottom of the page. Somehow the <%= yield %> seem to cause some problems. I got my nav above the <%= yield %> and it is displaying correctly, then there is my dynamic content, then I would like to have a footer.  Despite trying so many times to fix it, my footer doesn't appear below the content (<%= yield %>) but instead in the middle of the content (behind it). Does anyone know how I can use bootstrap with my app and create a footer that is pushed to the bottom of the page (below the content). It would be nice to be able to include it in the application.html.erb file. My footer is a simple:

```
<footer class="footer">
  <div class="container">
    <p class="text-muted">Place sticky footer content here.</p>
  </div>
</footer>
```

With the css

```
.footer {
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
height: 60px;
bottom:0;
background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
```

Thanks alot in advance!

/Jacob

Comment: Do you want to add the footer dynamically or just add it to the main layout (application.html.erb)?

Comment: Hi Guillermo! I got two layout files; home.html.erb for my homepage and the application.html.erb for the rest of the pages. But I got quite a lot of pages so I thought its best to have the footer in my two layout files.

Comment: I guess that you already try to add the <footer> tag into the layouts, it should works but paste to check it. Perhaps the problem is the browser that does not support the tag. Check the browser version here http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_footer.asp

Comment: Other silly remark: could be other css definition for footer class?. Try removing class attribute of footer tag and use type selector for footer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want your footer to appear after all the content, then you must not use `position: absolute;` -> this tells it to stick to the same place on the screen regardless of where the content is (in this case at the bottom of the screen, even when you are partway through the content of the page).

If you just want it to appear at the bottom of the content always - then just put it into the content after the yield (becuase that's the main page content) and remove the `position: absolute`.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the "footer" tag. Instead, try this:

```
<div id="footer">
  * Your text here *
</div>
```

And then change your CSS to this:

```
#footer {
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
height: 60px;
bottom:0;
background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
```

Finally, place the footer beneath the <%= yield %> tag, so that the dynamic content that you want displayed comes before the footer.

If that doesn't work, do this:

Go to the file with your dynamic content, and add the "div" footer beneath it. Using a "footer" tag can be problematic, so try to avoid using it.

Also, you'll need to add the footer to your homepage and application templates to see it on all your pages.

Hope this helps. Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Thanks. But no matter how I do it, it drops down to the bottom of the screen (to the bottom of the laptop screen) but then stays there even though there is more content below. Very strange...